# How does docker kill the healthcheck process after timeout?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to reverse engineer or find the go code (I searched through the code to no avail) to determine how docker kills a healthcheck command at a timeout.

This [issue on github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/43737) seems to imply there is a `SIGTERM` followed by a `SIGKILL`, but I am unable to trap it and log it to see the delay between the two.  An `strace` `dockerd` hasn't shown me how it does it either, nor does tracing the `docker run`.

The following code just logs the numbers 0-4 during the docker run:

```
$ cat healthcheck.c 
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fp = NULL;

void catch(int signo) {
   fprintf(fp, "caught: %d\n", signo);
   fflush(fp);
}

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGTERM, catch);
    signal(SIGINT, catch);
    signal(SIGHUP, catch);

    fp = fopen("/tmp/healthcheck.log", "a");

    for(int i = 0; i < 3600; i++) {
        sleep(1);
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", i);
        fflush(fp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04 as base
COPY healthcheck /
HEALTHCHECK --interval=1s --timeout=5s CMD ["/healthcheck"]
CMD sleep 60
```

Answer (score 1):

Per this [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/45927#issuecomment-1630875905) on the project, `SIGKILL` is the standard way the healthcheck is terminated now.  To quote,

> [...] health checks are not expected to have side-effects, and not expected to require a "graceful" shutdown when they time out.